# Area covered by multiple (possibly intersecting) circles on surface of sphere

Tags: circles, spherical-geometry, geodesic, stochastic-approximation

I have a number of circles of same radius on surface of sphere (Google Maps API). I'm trying to calculate the total area covered by these possibly intersecting circles.

My current solution is stochastic Monte Carlo sampling using 10,000 points (I know how to check if point is inside any circle). It gives me a pretty good approximation, but is really slow.

Is there a more efficient analytic solution?

Comment: What points are inside/outside the equator?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, sorry. I have circles on surface of sphere like so: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple Circles are distributed randomly on sphere (maybe intersecting). I'm trying to calculate total area they cover. Why equator?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense @zavidovych.  There's confusion because geodesic circles on a sphere are specifically great circles.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KajHansen, I removed 'geodesic' from question title and body.